# Blueprint script executed on tick but not on construction

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

Below, on event tick, I am initializing a map of images *once*, which works fine (remember we are in a graph for a widget blueprint here).

[image]

*Z Cursor Images* is the map of the images. The keys in the map are an enum, and I am adding first an image for the default cursor, and then an image for when the player is targeting an object that she can pick up.

Now, when I do *the same* in the construction script (Event Construct), it does not throw an error but later I cannot access the textures from the map. `IsValid` returns false for them...

So why *is* the map filled on tick but not on Event Construct? And how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are running into a limitation that's specific to the Construction Script, you can also try other approaches. Either:

- doing the initialization in ***Event Begin Play*** instead of the ***Construction script***
- providing the *Z Cursor Images* variable with default values that suits your needs instead of programmatically setting them at start

Cheers!